# Spark - build list of sorted results by summing until a threshold value is met

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a text file, where I need print the most frequently occuring words (and their number of occurences) in descending order until the words I have printed total *n* percentage of the total document.

I've written the following code so far:

```
// Break the file into words
val lines = sc.textFile("somefile.txt")
val words = lines.flatMap(line => line.split(" "))
words.persist()

val wordCount = words.count()
val wordCounts = words.map(word => (word, 1)).reduceByKey{case (x, y) => x + y}
// This is how many occurrences are needed to make up 3%
val occurencesNeeded = (0.03 * wordCount).ceil
```

My thought was to then use `top()` to find the most frequently occuring word (and remove/pop it from the list, repeating this until I have a total of 3%. I'm not sure how to turn this into code though, or if this is the right way to go about this problem.

Comment: Why can't you the windows functions to find the Rank or cumulative sum and then put a where/filter condition on the result? (This is an option if you are ready to have the data in data frames, spark-SQL) https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-functions-windows.html

Comment: It's a course assignment for learning Spark - so that would be out of scope.

Comment: Oh, then I should not be helping you any further :( Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea consists in finding the less popular word after which including another less popular word would bypass the number of words needed to reach 3%.

```
val words = sc.textFile("somefile.txt").flatMap(_.split(" "))
words.persist()

val nbrOfWords = words.count()
val occurencesNeeded = (0.03 * nbrOfWords).ceil

val wordCounts = words.map(word => (word, 1)).reduceByKey(_ + _).cache()

words.unpersist()
wordCounts.persist()

val countThreshold =
  wordCounts.values.collect.sorted
    // (accumulator, threshold, reachedThreshold)
    .foldRight(0, Int.MaxValue, false) {
      case (count, (accumulator, threshold, false)) => {
        if (accumulator + count <= occurencesNeeded)
          (accumulator + count, count, false)
        else (accumulator, threshold, true)
      }
      // If threshold has already been found, we skip the rest:
      case (count, (accumulator, threshold, true)) =>
        (accumulator, threshold, true)
    }
    ._2

val result =
  wordCounts.filter { case (word, count) => count >= countThreshold }

wordCounts.unpersist()

result.collect.foreach(println)
```

---

Let's say we have this set of word counts:

```
(("a", 34), ("b", 12), ("c", 9), ("d", 8), ...)
```

and 3% of the total number of raw words is `49`.

Then we go through this list and for each word (from the most popular to the least), if its number of occurrence plus the number of occurrences of most popular words is bellow `49`, then we modify the threshold under which we don't keep words to its count.

- `("a", 34)` since `34` is inferior to `49`, then the new threshold abve which we keep words is `34`.
- `("b", 12)` since `34 + 12 = 46` is inferior to 49, then the threshold becomes `12` and the number of words these 2 most popular words represent is `46`.
- `("c", 9)` since `46 + 9 = 55` is now superior to 49, then this word and all less popular words will be discarded. Thus the final word count threshold above which we keep words is `12`.
- And we don't take into account the rest of less popular words.

---

Note that during the `foldRight` stage, we use a `Boolean` to "stop" considering less popular words when the threshold we needed is obtained. This is required, since `("c", 9)` would make the cumulative word count above `49`, but `("s", 2)` would be inferior than `49` and thus the threshold would become `2`!

---

*Note: this solution collects the list of unique words on the driver, which could become an issue if you have very limited memory on the driver. But that would be surprising as the number of unique words in your file should probably not be bigger than ~20K.*

Comment: Wow, what a solid answer. Thanks, I've learned a lot here. And also, I would argue that we should _never_ need to worry about words overflowing the driver, since the english language in it's entirety can be fit into a fairly small text file.